# Root user is denied downloading from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

Using `s3cmd` after configuring with my root privileges (access key and secret key), whenever I try to download something from a bucket using `sync` or `get` , I receive this strange error of permission for my root account:

```
WARNING: Remote file  S3Error: 403 (Forbidden):
```

The owner is another user I have made using IAM console, but am I correct to expect that the root user should always get full and unrestricted access? 
Also using `aws`-cli i get an unknown error

```
A client error (Unknown) occurred when calling the GetObject operation: Unknown
```

Also I thought I had to add a bucket policy to allow for root access (as strange as it sounds), as the first step I added annonymous access with this policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But still the errors are the same as above. The owner of the bucket is also the root user (the one trying to access is the same as owner). What am I understanding wrong here? How can I restore root user's access to my own bucket that was made by one of my own IAM users?

Comment: Have you checked your bucket ACLs?  Also, have you attempted a simple HTTP/S GET without using the `aws-cli` or `s3cmd`?  Anonymous access for the bucket policy above should allow for anonymous requests outside of AWS authentication.  I know that doesn't answer the question but it could help identify where the issue is.

Comment: Thanks. It could be a scenario where I have previously (using web console) made a bucket, but after that I have uploaded using `s3cmd` possibly with different credentials. And now trying to download with root credentials. `s3cmd setacl --acl-grant=all:canonicalID --recursive s3://bucket` does not work. Also, I do not know what "simple HTTP/S GET" means.

Comment: "doesn't work" means that after using `setacl` there is no problem and it says "ACL updated" but the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always a good idea to recheck the status of storage, and whether S3 has been under a life cycle, so that in this case it could have been transferred to Glacier. Here,  I tried to access a Glacier object using `s3cmd` commands, and I received uninformative and irrelevant permission errors. It would be a good idea to add this as an enhancement to future versions of `s3cmd` to get better warning/error messages.

Answer (score 2):

For any of the S3 read permissions to work, you need not just allow those objects but also allow `ListBucket` on the bucket(s), `ListAllMyBuckets` and `GetBucketLocation`, my consolidated version:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:Get*",
            "s3:List*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

See more examples at [AWS IAM Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/ExampleIAMPolicies.html#iam-policy-example-s3)